# What is the best cocoa book for desktop mac development?

Tags: cocoa, macos, desktop

I'm learning iphone dev, and also want a solid handle at desktop development for the mac.

What do you guys recommend?

Language wise, is objective-c all I need?

Is desktop development locked down at all, or are you free to do anything once it is installed?

Does each app run in its own space as to not effect other desktop apps?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Book recomendations for learning Cocoa programming?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/945600/book-recomendations-for-learning-cocoa-programming)

Comment: See also [Cocoa and Objective-C resources?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571/cocoa-and-objective-c-resources)

Comment: good question, and the answer was good in 2011. but are there any newer books, now, in 2014?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. *[Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321503619)* is generally regarded as "the bible" of desktop Cocoa development.
2. Objective-C is all you need, for the most part.  Very rarely will you need a more domain-specific language.  There are more options (MacRuby, PyObjC, Java, REALbasic, etc), but it's extremely common to do everything in Objective-C.
3. Any "lockdown" on the desktop would be defined by the app store approval process and the permissions you can acquire from the user.
4. <strike>Apps are not sandboxed on the Mac.</strike>

Answer (score 0):

Note that Edition 5 of 'Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X' is based on using Swift rather than using Objective-C. Big Nerd Ranch do have other Object-C based books. With there being so much work at the moment converting Obj-C libraries to Swift, it would still be handy to be familiar with both.

There is also a follow-up book by the same author: 'Advanced Cocoa Programming for the Mac OS X'.

So many Cocoa programming books focus on iOS, so it's good to have books that focus on the Mac platform exclusively. And these are very good ones!